# Where do I download FBProfileExpressionKit?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.x

I've read the docs here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/profile-expression-kit/ios/ several times, and I've downloaded the Facebook SDK from here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/downloads. That download doesn't contain the needed `FBProfileExpressionKit` framework to integrate with the Profile Expression Kit SDK, and the site itself doesn't have a link to download it. Where the heck do I do download `FBProfileExpressionKit` from?

Answer (score 1):

I searched but there is no option in FBProfileExpressionKit Documentation.

You can download `FBProfileExpressionKit` from [here](http://www.fbxin.com/profile-expression-kit/profile-expression-kit-ios-documentation/)

You can upload photo and video as follow

```
[FBSDKProfileExpressionSharer uploadProfilePictureFromData:videoData metadata:nil];

[FBSDKProfileExpressionSharer uploadProfilePictureFromUIImage:uiimage metadata:nil];
```

[More Info](http://%20https://developers.facebook.com/docs/profile-expression-kit)

Comment: Welcome @TimJohnsen

Comment: I also reverse engineered their SDK and wrote my own, gonna post that here and on GitHub when I have time

Comment: Great. @TimJohnsen

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I wound up doing it (I reverse engineered how the SDK embedded in another app was sending the message to Facebook's app): https://github.com/timonus/TJFacebookProfileExpression.